# radio group not working and vertical alignment android

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group

```
JSONArray jsonQuestion = new JSONArray(obj.get("question").toString());
for (int iii = 0; iii < jsonQuestion.length(); iii++) {
    LinearLayout lll = new LinearLayout(Questionnaire.this);
    lll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);


    JSONObject obj2 = (JSONObject) jsonQuestion.get(iii);
    System.out.println(obj2.get("question"));

    TextView tv = new TextView(Questionnaire.this);

    tv.setText(obj2.get("question").toString());
    lll.addView(tv);




    JSONArray jsonAnswer = new JSONArray(obj.get("answer").toString());
    Log.d("Reading Answer: ", jsonAnswer + "");

    for (int iiii = 0; iiii < jsonAnswer.length(); iiii++) {
        JSONObject obj3 = (JSONObject) jsonAnswer.get(iiii);
        System.out.println(obj2.get("questiosysid").toString().matches(obj3.get("questionid").toString()));
        if (obj2.get("questiosysid").toString().matches(obj3.get("questionid").toString())) {
            TextView tv1 = new TextView(Questionnaire.this);
            tv1.setText(obj3.get("inputname").toString());


            RadioGroup group = new RadioGroup(Questionnaire.this);
            group.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL); // RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL or RadioGroup.VERTICAL

            if (obj3.get("inputtype").toString().matches("radio")) {

                RadioButton newRadioButton = new RadioButton(Questionnaire.this);
                newRadioButton.setId(Integer.parseInt(obj3.get("answerid").toString()));
                newRadioButton.setText(obj3.get("inputname").toString());
                group.addView(newRadioButton);


                lll.addView(group);

            }







        }

    }
    ll.addView(lll);

}
```

This is my code for dynamically adding radio button.

Problem is when I select one option then select anther it does not deselect the previous one. **Why doesn't it deselect the the first one selecting another** when they are both added to same radio group. Also it is not placing the radio buttons next to each other but on top of each other when the **orientation is set to horizontal**

**UPDATE**

I moved my declaration of

```
RadioGroup group = new RadioGroup(Questionnaire.this);
group.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL); // RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL or RadioGroup.VERTICAL
```

out side parent for loop now i am getting

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

How should i deal with it?

Comment: "...when they are both added to same radio group." - Are you sure they're all in the same `RadioGroup`? It looks like you're creating a new `RadioGroup` for each new `RadioButton`. This probably explains your orientation problem, too.

Comment: @MikeM. i have it in for loop so i moved it outside because of what you said now i am getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.` how should i deal with it? i have a question loop inside is the answer loop just out side the answer loop i have declared `RadioGroup group = new RadioGroup(Questionnaire.this);
    group.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL); // RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL or RadioGroup.VERTICAL`

Comment: can you post your entire xml and java code ? `IllegalstateException` occurs because view your trying to add is already added to some other layout.

Comment: @rajanks updated the code. original one. the one which selects both radio button. i have no xml i dynamically add all view

Comment: try to make object of linearlayout out side loop.

Comment: can you explain a bit more @VishalThakkar can you name which lay out i have 2 layout the outer layout and the inner one. i would like to have 1 inner for each question that is why i have it inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are added only one `RadioButton` in `RadioGroup` that's why you got many selected radio button. `RadioGroup` need minimum 2 `RadioButton` for check or Uncheck effect.

try this,I hope it may work.

```
JSONArray jsonQuestion = new JSONArray(obj.get("question").toString());

for (int iii = 0; iii < jsonQuestion.length(); iii++) {
    LinearLayout lll = new LinearLayout(Questionnaire.this);
    lll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    JSONObject obj2 = (JSONObject) jsonQuestion.get(iii);
    System.out.println(obj2.get("question"));

    TextView tv = new TextView(Questionnaire.this);
    tv.setText(obj2.get("question").toString());
    lll.addView(tv);

    JSONArray jsonAnswer = new JSONArray(obj.get("answer").toString());
    Log.d("Reading Answer: ", jsonAnswer + "");

    RadioGroup group = new RadioGroup(Questionnaire.this);
    group.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL); // RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL or RadioGroup.VERTICAL

   for (int iiii = 0; iiii < jsonAnswer.length(); iiii++) {
        JSONObject obj3 = (JSONObject) jsonAnswer.get(iiii);
        System.out.println(obj2.get("questiosysid").toString().matches(obj3.get("questionid").toString()));
        if (obj2.get("questiosysid").toString().matches(obj3.get("questionid").toString())) {
            TextView tv1 = new TextView(Questionnaire.this);
            tv1.setText(obj3.get("inputname").toString());

            if (obj3.get("inputtype").toString().matches("radio")) {
                RadioButton newRadioButton = new RadioButton(Questionnaire.this);
                newRadioButton.setId(Integer.parseInt(obj3.get("answerid").toString()));
                newRadioButton.setText(obj3.get("inputname").toString());
                group.addView(newRadioButton);
            }
        }
    }
    lll.addView(group);
    ll.addView(lll);
}
```

Comment: hi can you add sort of explanation so i can see what i did wrong and how you fix it?

Comment: can you explain why you put the `lll.addView(group);
    ll.addView(lll);` out side?

Comment: if you put that line inside inner loop than it's add only one radio button in one RadioGroup, but in this case all RadioButton of inner loop added in one RadioGroup.

Answer (score 0):

try like  this i have make code as you want.

```
     ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.templayout);
    LinearLayout mLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    mLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    mLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    scrollView.addView(mLinearLayout);
    JSONArray jsonQuestion = new JSONArray(obj.get("question").toString());

    for (int iii = 0; iii < jsonQuestion.length(); iii++) {


        JSONObject obj2 = (JSONObject) jsonQuestion.get(iii);
        System.out.println(obj2.get("question"));

        TextView tv = new TextView(Questionnaire.this);
        tv.setText(obj2.get("question").toString());
        mLinearLayout.addView(tv);

        JSONArray jsonAnswer = new JSONArray(obj.get("answer").toString());
        Log.d("Reading Answer: ", jsonAnswer + "");

        RadioGroup group = new RadioGroup(Questionnaire.this);
        group.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL); // RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL or RadioGroup.VERTICAL

        for (int iiii = 0; iiii < jsonAnswer.length(); iiii++) {
            JSONObject obj3 = (JSONObject) jsonAnswer.get(iiii);
            System.out.println(obj2.get("questiosysid").toString().matches(obj3.get("questionid").toString()));
            if (obj2.get("questiosysid").toString().matches(obj3.get("questionid").toString())) {
                TextView tv1 = new TextView(Questionnaire.this);
                tv1.setText(obj3.get("inputname").toString());

                if (obj3.get("inputtype").toString().matches("radio")) {
                    RadioButton newRadioButton = new RadioButton(Questionnaire.this);
                    newRadioButton.setId(Integer.parseInt(obj3.get("answerid").toString()));
                    newRadioButton.setText(obj3.get("inputname").toString());
                    group.addView(newRadioButton);
                }
            }
        }
        mLinearLayout.addView(group);
    }
}
```